# Call a Task when a property has been updated

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, catel

in a WPF MVVM (Catel) Application I've to call a

```
Task<DateTime> GetDateFor(int portfolio, int currency);
```

Right now what I'm doing is

```
if (e.HasPropertyChanged(() => SelectedCross))
{
    using (StartInternalChange())
    {
        await GetDateFor(1,2);
    }
}
```

and as Geert from Catel told me it's not a good approach and I agree with you that doing async void is not a good practice, considering the fact I wish not to change my repository implementation to serve data synchronously what can I do?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may just be a point of perspective but in my opinion performing async void or more precisely async Task in event handlers is perfectly OK, in fact :

> Void-returning async methods have a specific purpose: to make asynchronous event handlers possible.

At least according to [Stephen Cleary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt149362?author=Stephen%20Cleary) , you can read more about it here :
[Async/Await - Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx)